What explains this dialogue sequence in the movie "Get Out"?
This conversation takes place in the movie, "Get Out" (2017).

P1: "I wasn't trying to snitch
P2: "Snitch?"
P1: "Rat you out"
P2: First looks quizzical, then: "Tattletale!"

P1 is the hero, a black person. P2 is also a black person, but it turns out it is an older white woman residing in the body of a young black female.
I believe the three words are synonymous of each other, but is there a particular time/race factor in the usage of the three words that make them more or less familiar to one demographic compared to another?

 The fact of the guy being black is central to the progress of the movie. But in direct terms, that's nothing to do with the fragment of dialogue you've cited (there's no allusion to race there). None of the terms snitch, rat out, tattletale have anything to do with the fact that the girl didn't tell her family that her latest boyfriend is black. But obviously that is central to the movie! In fact, all of those slang/ idiomatic verbs are synonymous with "betray" - they're typical of middle-class white British speakers, not remotely associated with AmE black speakers.

Well, rat  out is 100% lower-class AmE, but snitch and tattletale are more typically BrE middle-class expressions. But that's not really relevant, In context, they're all just "race-agnostic" synonyms. Look elsewhere for the message of the movie (which is well worth the watch, as I recall). The movie is aimed at the international market, imho.

Actually, this usage chart suggests that snitch (as both verb and noun) temporarily gained much traction in AmE, which is now falling off. I haven't checked the subtitles, but maybe JK Rowling used it in the Harry Potter books / movies.

Tattle tale (meaning "A revealer of secrets; an informer") appears in Maurice Weseen, Dictionary of American Slang (1934) under the heading of "General Slang." In Texas in the early 1960s, young children would chant at a peer who "told on them" to adults in positions of authority: "Tattletale, tattletale, sitting on a bull's tail!" With or without the chant, tattletale was a common term at that time. Snitch in the sense of "inform on" has been in U.S. English since about 1920. Wentworth & Flexner, American Slang Dictionary (1960) describe this slang verb as "Common since c1920."

@FumbleFingers: If there is no race connotation to the dialogue, then the only logic I can figure is the age - perhaps "tattletale" is a word older people tend to use, and "snitch" and "rat out" are younger people's usage, which the grandmother (inside the black woman's body) finds it difficult to pick.

Yes, that's right, Bravo. tattletale is fuddy-duddy, and not limited to BrE speakers at all. The others are slang. "grass", "fit up" for snitch are the BrE words I hear in UK police procedurals.

I think @Lambie has nailed it. Before the Internet, rat [someone] out was virtually unknown by comparison with tattetale. But over the last couple of decades the latter has moved up to the top slot.

So either the scriptwriter got lucky, or he specifically chose the words to reflect the older woman's likely vocabulary. Nothing to do with race, though. Just age.

Snitch and tattletale are interchangeable in Am E, regardless of race, but tattletale was the polite word for children to use, especially in school. Admittedly tattletale has fallen out of usage, but if you used it in your youth . . .  Today, prison rules dominate classrooms, so "snitches get stitches" is a common expression and attitude.

Snitch and even moreso rat out are commonly associated with the criminal underworld, at least in the US. In contrast tattle-tale is more associated with the US South.
Green's Dictionary of Slang has many references for snitch: it occurs in the UK from the 18th century, and in the early 20th century across the US including a 1911 book of Arkansas slang. But the dominant usage is in crime stories, from WM Raine in 1909: ‘Say, Jimmie, C’n you keep a secret?’ ‘Sure. Course I can.’ ‘Won’t ever snitch?’ Through Nicholas Pileggi's 1985 mafia classic Wiseguys: Even the hacks who [...] couldn’t be bribed would never snitch on the guys who did. and right up into the 21st century. The OED has snitch as a verb from 1801 in the UK, with various 20th century American references such as Arthur Miller (A View from the Bridge) and Budd Schulberg (What makes Sammy Run?), writers who attempted to represent life in American immigrant communities, so nothing very literary.
Green's has a host of references for rat out from 1975 in crime writer Edwin Torres, through a long list of famous American crime writers like Carl Hiaasen and Pileggi again. So it's very strongly associated with the criminal underworld. The OED doesn't have rat out. So it's a more recent criminal term.
Green's doesn't even have an entry for tattletale or tattle tale. The OED has a range of literary references from Mary Murfree (writing as CE Craddock) in 1889 -  a wealthy Southern US writer known for tales of Appalachian life. There is also Faulkner and Carson McCullers, so it's reasonable to suggest an association with the Southern US.

Tattle-tale is not confined to the US South.  I'm from Pennsylvania in the northeast part of the country and it was a word kids used here.

Carl Hiassen is always laugh out loud. Unbelievable. Read his books, folks.

@TimR Same for me from Long Island, NY. I'm pretty sure it's widespread in English, as I probably heard it on national TV.

Novelist Sarah Orne Jewett used the word "tattle-tale" in her *Tales of New England *(1888).
